# MySQL Interface with LabView - LabView is Freezing

Tags: mysql, cron, labview

I have a LabView data acquisition system that is writing data to a MySQL Database.  It is writing data every second.  The LabView system recently froze around the time when I was playing with the SQL queries.

I have a client computer, which is supposed to send queries to that MySQL Database every hour.  This client computer set up a cron job to send the command to query the database every hour.

I recently added an index to my time_stamp, in order to optimize my query.

This may be a shot in the dark, but could there be any deleterious interaction between the fact that I had created an index on our time_stamp (to optimize the query), and set up a cron job to send the query every hour?  Around that time, I think I may have also sent a query and aborted quickly before it completed, so I was wondering if something like that may cause the LabView system to freeze?

It doesn't appear to be an issue on the MySQL side, because the server was still running.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you currently have deadlocks at your MySQL server, the query from your LabVIEW application might be suspended and is waiting for completion forever. Hint, look to the query execution time. Why it is happened should be investigated separately, but there is a good chance that if you just kill that suspended query the system will unfreeze and keeps running normally.

Comment: On the client computer, I am running the query in the terminal and it appears to finish executing.  (My data is saved, and a new line in the terminal is starting).

Comment: Can you stop and start over your LabVIEW system? That may resolve the issue.

Comment: Yeah, restarting LabView (and the host computer) resolved the problem of the frozen LabView.  But ideally, it is not feasible for me to run the query if it will freeze my LabView each hour that I want to run it.

Comment: @Gary You told that you did modification of your tables. That may cause freezing if that table was in use at the moment. Same may happened if you modify a stored procedure or function which is currently in use. Changes applied between calls are ok, but it can be situation depending of design that something in use all the time, than you need to stop application before applying changes. Let it run for some time and see if freeze will repeat again.

Comment: Good point.  I am writing data to my table every second, and the other day, I created an index on the time_stamp to speed up my queries.  So you think that there could be something funky going on because of this?

Comment: Yes it could. Just today I had a similar situation when changing of function that concurrently been running by three clients caused a deadlock.

Comment: Okay, I will investigate to see if it happens again.  The problem is, my table has over 2 million rows, and I need to Query on the Time_Stamp column.  So if I don't have the Index on the time_stamp column, then my query takes forever (as opposed to a couple seconds).  Do you know of any other workarounds?

Comment: BTW, this is really not LabVIEW but databases question. In my experience, the best you can do for LabVIEW to database interaction is to put as much database related logic as you can in the database itself, so your application do not manage any internal database businesses. I really recommend to do not run direct SQL queries from your application, but use stored procedures as your interface from LabVIEW to database.

Comment: You could queue the data to another loop in LabVIEW so that the DB insert is done from there and this can then handle when there is a table lock or anything. LabVIEW will continue to acquire your data but can handle a delay in processing the SQL. You could also then wait until you have 60 seconds worth of data and wrap it in a transaction to make it less susceptible to table locks